# How can we configure Firebase to have a unique record of a certain row?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let say I have this data in my database in Firebase.

When query them, this is the snap of my `users` table.

```
Snap (users) {
    "-LT4EcyIm--lMAQQqKSR" =     {
        fcmToken = "abc";
        phone = 9786770861;
    };
```

I want to insert a next record only `fcmToken != "abc";` because fcmToken must be unique.

How can we configure Firebase to have a unique record of a certain row ?

---

## Code

```
func storeToFirebaseDatabase() {

    let email = "johndoe@gmail.com"
    let password = "tsnu123"
    let phone = "9786470861"

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in

        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let usersReference = ref.child("users")
        let id = usersReference.childByAutoId().key


        InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID(handler: { (result, error) in
            let token = result?.instanceID

            let fcmToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "fcmToken")

            let values =
                ["phone": phone,
                 "CreatedAt":self.dateToString(date: Date()),
                 "UpdatedAt":self.dateToString(date: Date()),
                 "fcmToken": fcmToken,
                ] as [String : Any]


            usersReference.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

                    print("--------")
                    print(snapshot)
                    print("--------")

                }
            })

            usersReference.child(id!).setValue(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                if err != nil {
                    print(err.self as Any)
                    return
                }
                print("Successfully saved user in Firebase DB")

            })

        })

    }
}
```

Comment: why do not you use ***push*** to generate fcmToken value?

Comment: The fcmToken is already generating as soon as the app load since the code is in the AppDelegate.

Comment: would validating fcmToken in realtime-database rules be useful? this would block the write and return permission denied. In this case it will be necessary to create a node with all the active values of fcmToken to validate with the rules.